# DIY sourcemeter

Tags: arduino, operational-amplifier, constant-current

I have been wanting to make a fourpoint probe setup for a while. I posted a question about it here and some people told me about operational amplifier constant current source and the non-inverting amplifier for measurement. I have been looking into it. What I want is a SMU that can provide a constant current and measure voltage at the same time. Commercially available units like Keithley are way too expensive. I just want a little device that has the same functionality, it doesn't have to be really accurate. Also I want to interface it with LabVIEW using arduino. I know some stuff about Op-amp current source and voltmeter but I don't know how to go about putting it all together it in one package and interface with LabVIEW. I'd be really grateful if any of you could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to a simple one based on an Arduino: [Arduino based source meter](http://pv.mit.edu/home/education/resources-for-educators/build-your-own-sourcemeter/).  It is limited in resolution and output capability but may be useful for basic experimentation.

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I saw this one but couldn't find these parts here in Pakistan. Also I want to make a four point probe, I want to have different terminals for passing current and measurement of voltage... could you help me with that.

Comment: There is nothing critical about the actual parts used - the same arrangement could be used with different opamps and digital to analog converter.  To provide 4 terminal capability add a differential amplifier for the voltage sensing.  It will provide the two independent voltage inputs.

Comment: Thanks man, this cleared my mind a lot.. I'll ask again if I need to

Comment: Hey, the circuit you mentioned above measures current at different voltages, I want to have a cc source run a current through the sample and measure voltage, is there something I can do with this circuit that'll let me do that, and sorry if I'm bothering you but I really need to this and I need some help.